# Does boundedness of $g(x,y)$ imply continuity of $f(x,y)=x\cdot g(x,y)$

Tags: calculus

Does boundedness of $g(x,y)$ imply continuity of $f(x,y)=x\cdot g(x,y)$?
My book gives the following hint: to prove that $f(x,y)$ is continuous show that it equals the product of $x$ and a bounded function. Is this true or does it 
apply under more suitable hypothesis on $g(x,y)$?

---

Exercise:
Define $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R} $ by setting $f(0)=0$, and:$$f(x,y)=xy(x^2-y^2)/(x^2+y^2) $$ if $(x,y)\ne0$. Show $f$ is of class $C^1$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$.
Hint: Show $Df_1(x,y)$ equals the product of $y$ and a bounded function, and  $Df_2(x,y)$ equals the product of $x$ and a bounded function.

Answer (score 1):

Well...that might work to show it's continuous ... but only at $x = 0$.

Consider $g(x, y) = u(x-1) u(y)$
where
$$
u(t) = \begin{cases}
-1 & t < 0\\
0 & t = 0\\
1 & t > 0
\end{cases}.
$$

That's certainly bounded, but $xg(x, y)$ is not continuous at $x = 1$, for instance.

Comment: I have to prove that $f$ is continuous on R^2

Comment: I'll edit and post the complete exercise

Comment: Well, in your example, the function's evidently continuous away from the origin, as it's the quotient of two continuous (indeed, polynomial) functions, with the denominator being nonzero. To prove continuity at zero, the hint given in the exercise should help...but perhaps not as directly as you were hoping when you asked your initial question.

Comment: And what happens if I suppose $x>0,g(x,y)>0$?

Comment: Add 7 to the function $u$, so that it takes on the values 6, 7, and 8; the resulting function $f$ will still be discontinuous at $x = 1$.